# UIScrollView overlays UIView but enables its touch events?

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, scroll, touch, overlay

Is it possible to handle both scrolling events for UIScrollView and touch events for UIView behind it?
I found out that UIView handles its touch events when UIScrollView disables its own user interaction only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inside your view add scrollview and in.h file write delegate `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>`

In your viewDidLoad write

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    [singleFingerTap release];

    scrl.scrollEnabled = YES; // scrl is my UIScrollView
    scrl.delegate = self;
    scrl.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 680);
    [self.view addSubview:scrl];
```

And in handleSingleTap method write your code. It will scroll also and if you tap on view then the handleSingleTap method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue while making a UIScrollView overlay a SpriteKit view, so that the user can scroll a large in-game menu. The scroll view 'steals' all taps and I can't push buttons behind the scroll view, like my 'back button'. I also had buttons in the scroll view that I had handlers for in my original sprite kit scene - and am loathed to move into my scrollable view.

So, I fixed this by simply sending all my touch events to both the super class and the superview.
I'm not sure if there's any big downside yet, but I now get touches and scrolling.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```